# ImageMagick how to -append output split in half

Tags: imagemagick

I'm newbie, any help is appreciated. I'll keep it short.

What I'm doing now is "magick *.jpg -append a.png".
This merges 100+ of .jpg vertically into a .png. Problem is its long so I wanna split it in half so I get shorter a.png and b.png instead of 1 long .png.

I would like to have a single code that does it because there is hundreds of these folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use montage for that in ImageMagick.

```
magick montage *.jpg -tile 2x -geometry +0+0 result.png
```

If you want space between files, then change +0+0 to use non-zero amounts for the spacing. Montage can also add file names under the images if you want using -label %f in the command

Comment: Thanks it kinda work but its continuing from right to left instead of left to right.
Is it possible to output it into 2 different .png rather than in 1?

EDIT: Nevermind it is from left to right.

Comment: I do not understand "right to left"?  The order depends upon the alphabetic ordering of your directory. It will put the first image on the left and the second on the right, then go to the next row from left to right. To do 2 pngs for the output, you have to split the list of images first and do montage twice. But I am not sure what you want. So can you post a diagram or example output of what you are getting now and what you want?

Comment: Sorry about that right to left thing, that was my mistake. I am combining all the Manhwa webtoon images into a long png. It was all seperated into small jpg when I downloaded it. Thanks for the answer but now that I think about it, it wouldn't work without manually going through all of it because some of the jpg break off half way in the Manhwa so I have to pick where each jpg end and start at the second half png.